# java.net.BindException: Address already in use on tomcat

Tags: tomcat8

I keep getting this bind exception in the logs while have tomcat process running.
It doesn't prohibit my process from start but still this is a problem.

> 05-Oct-2017 13:42:47.896 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point
>   associated with ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-*********-not 8080 port"]  java.net.BindException: Address
>   already in use
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
>       at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
>       at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:842)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
>
> 05-Oct-2017 13:42:47.898 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to
>   initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.
>   1-non 8080 port]]  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-non 8080 port]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:842)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484) Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler
>   initialization failed
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       ... 12 more Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
>       at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
>       at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)

What have I tried already:

```
lsof | grep -i process/port/ip
netstat -tlnp
```

I tried to find if any other application is using the port or not. But no other application is using it.

It is free linux centos.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange.
ok.
Even the SEVERE exception is there in the logs of catalina but I can get to the server and get landing page.
Still I have to figure out why did it keep writing that Exception.